# Why I can't import NSConcreteMapTable?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, foundation

I want add some items in NSConcreteMapTable of CBCentralManager from CoreBluetooth framework. But I wander that I can't import this Class in my project? Why? And how cold I fix it?

```
_peripheral = [[NSClassFromString(@"CBPeripheral") alloc] init];
[_peripheral setValue:@"P_Mote" forKey:@"name"];
[_peripheral setValue:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"7811962A-4A72-FA7F-856C-E8EAADE1452E"] forKey:@"identifier"];
NSConcreteMapTable *perif = [self.centralManager valueForKey:@"_peripherals"];
```

NSConcreteMapTable is not imported although I added `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

Comment: `NSConcreteMapTable`? I guess that should be `NSMapTable` instead. "ZzZConcreteZzZ` classes usually seems to be internal classes/clusters.

Comment: http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=Foundation.framework&header=NSConcreteMapTable.h   it exists. and is using in NSCentralManager

Comment: Are you trying to use private classes? Because, I haven't found `NSConcreteMapTable` in the Doc, nor in the `NSFoundation.framework` headers files. And the link from where you get the doc, seems clearly indicate that's an internal class.

Comment: Something tricky with this class. I will try operate with NSMapTable as you said. Maybe it will be enough.

Comment: trying to mess with the peripheral's table of CBCentralManager is probably not going to end well.  The fact that you had to jump through hoops just to create an instance of CBPeripheral should be a hint

Comment: Yes, guis, I understood that creating CBPeripheral by hand was bad idea. So I will finish this. Thank all!